# Getting a TabError

Tags: django-apps

I am absolutely new to Django and Python and is following a tutorial someone did a few years ago to the letter.  I have the following code snippet and when I save it my development Django server give me a error message:
File: "/path/to/my/file/apps.py", line 7
def ready(self):
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

```
 from django.apps import AppConfig


 class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
     name = 'users'

     def ready(self):
         import users.signals
```

When I save the file I get the error message above.  I also have another file very similar to this one and that one works well.  Any idea where I need to change?  This code is part of code to create a profile for a user on the site when the user registers on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def` needs to be under `name`. You had added an extra space before `def`.

To avoid such errors in the future, use a better Text Editor or try out online auto-formatters.

Proper code-

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):

    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```